# Cannot place the forearm on the correct low position while I'm playing with the armature

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I'm a blender newbie and I'm trying to animate my first character on blender. Actually I'm playing with the armature, but it seems to me that Blender uses a confusing procedure for this matter. Anyways ,as you can see from the attached pictures, I'm not able to move the right forearm to the correct low position. Can you explain to me why?

Please go to this website :

http://www.psychonews.it/pics/

and check these pictures :

2014-12-07_19-08-52.png ;
2014-12-07_19-09-22.png ;
2014-12-07_19-09-45.png ;

thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with correct low position? Do you want the right arm to be attached to the body?

Comment: In pose mode I'm not able to move the whole right arm from from the horizontal position to the vertical one...

Comment: Could you upload your Blend file? Use this link: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33248

Comment: I can't see anything inherently wrong. So I don't understand what you want to achieve. I can move the arm like a normal armature: http://pbrd.co/1yJfiLm

Comment: Hello. you have been able to do what I want. How you do that ? Are you in pose mode ? can you make a short video for me to show me the steps involved ? thanks...

Comment: Hello man. I have created the armature of another character and I'm able to move the forearm only pressing the "G" key. This time it doesn't work but I need to press the "R" key. Why ?

Comment: It depends on your rig. A guess would be that the bones of your other armature are connected at the shoulder. So that your chest bone is in contact with the shoulder bone(without the stippled lines) and your shoulder bone is in contact with your upper arm(again without those lines). When you use "G" the bone might be constrained, so instead of moving position, it ends up rotating. However, that's not a good way of using a FK rig. It's better to use "R" in this case.

Comment: Test and see if "R" works on the other rig as well. It's most likely luck that "G" worked for rotation =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your one of your arm-bones while in pose mode, and press R. You can then rotate that bone using the mouse. The bone rotates according to your screen, so go to front/back(numpad 1/ctrl + numpad 1) view to get straight rotation.

To go from the images you posted to what I posted, you need to rotate the upper arm and the lower arm =)

Image I posted:
[image]